# Serving static content using Nginx after successful NodeJS authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, jwt

**Context:**

I'm trying to build a webapp with Nginx acting as the front end server and also as a proxy to my NodeJS server in the backend. I want to restrict access to the functional part of the webapp via proper authentication mechanism. The authentication logic is handled by NodeJS server and uses JWTs to handle the same.

**Current flow:**

1. The static login page is shown to the user which is being served by Nginx.
2. User credentials are sent to the Nginx server which is forwarded to the NodeJS server which handles the login logic and on successful authentication sends back a JWT token. (All www.baseurl.com/api requests are being forwarded to NodeJS server)
3. The JWT is stored in localStorage of the client browser (recommendation by Auth0 team) and then I want to redirect the user to the functional webapp page (say /home).
4. For redirect, I am requesting access to /api/home page to Nginx server with my JWT token. This request is forwarded to NodeJS for validation of the token. Once validated I need to serve the webapp functional home page which is mixture of .html, .css, .js files.
5. Since the page in itself is first rendered static and then it makes ajax requests to load further content, I want to serve this home page from my Nginx server rather than sending the whole HTML string from Node JS server. And once the static page is loaded on the client machine I want to start making requests to Node server requesting further page contents depending on permissions of the user.

**Problem statement:**

How can I achieve the same using Node and Nginx? How can Nginx know that NodeJS has validated the user token in step 4 and then serve the static part of the home page?

Is this even possible? What is the best recommended way to handle such cases of authentication flow?

**PS:** I'm using ExpressJS framework on server side, and plain html/css/js for client side (No client side web frameworks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the solution that involves below steps:

1. Serve static login page using Nginx
2. Forward the login credentials to the NodeJS server where authentication is handled and auth-token is stored in the response cookie (http-only). Send this response with the cookie set to the client
3. Once the client receives authentication message, on success request the secure webapp page. This request will carry the auth-cookie along with itself.

   4. Again forward the request to the NodeJS server from Nginx, validate the token, set **X-Accel-Redirect** header with the path where to look for the secure file on NodeJS server.

While using X-Accel-Redirect, special care needs to be taken for Mime-Type of the response.

- CSS needs to be served with text/css
- images needs to be served with images/jpeg
- HTML content should be served with text/html

Comment: I'm looking for this damn feature a long time ago :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two solutions to this problem.

#### 1. Validate the token at NGINX level

You are using Auth0 right? They made a library to validate JWT tokens with Nginx & Lua. So follow [their tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nginx) and you should be good.

#### 2. Don't validate the token

I believe that the sensitive part of a single page application resides in its data and backend algorithms. The front HTML, CSS and JS files (in most cases) don't need to be secured! And it's probably impossible to secure them. One could just create an account, get all your *secured* files and expose them on a public website. Keep It Stupid Simple. If it's not useful to secure those files, don't do it!

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for both the suggestions though I was looking for a better redirection solution after authentication using Node JS!